# Load a youtube video in uiwebview, and when played it doesnt go fullscreen

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube, resize

As for now i have been using this solution I found on the internet to load a youtube video in uiwebview

```
[_youTubeView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/XeIKnBDN4To"]]];
```

when it plays it goes into fullscreen in portrait mode and runs the video but throws out this error

```
setting movie path: http://r1---sn-uxajvoxu-btxe.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?itag=18&sver=3&
expire=1361830325&sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mt=1361804717&mv=m&id=5de20a9c10cde13a&upn=0EXPt7MQ7SY&cp=U0hVRlhOTl9HT0NONV9QSFJEOmFndEpDMDA3Q21k&
source=youtube&newshard=yes&ms=au&key=yt1&ip=186.3.143.22&
fexp=917000%2C909708%2C900504%2C900222%2C916625%2C902544%2C920704%2C912806%2C902000%2C922403%2C922405
%2C929901%2C913605%2C925006%2C906938%2C931202%2C908529%2C920201%2C930101%2C906834%2C926403%2C901451&
ratebypass=yes&ipbits=8&cpn=_--u0dVaHxrCxseN&
signature=6E11DBCDC8A2585C102A4A1191636C129D04561D.84546ADF1034D266AE4258360BBBC59D0D1FD9BB
```

Is it the correct approach to load a youtube video, and how avoid going into fullscreen?

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to prevent full screen, as the UIWebView will not play YouTube videos itself, rather it loads up the Video Player...

Comment: And the issue of that error popping up, how do i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods to view YouTube videos inline without Apple's special recognition of them. There are libraries and [categories](https://github.com/enigmaticflare/UIWebView-YouTube--iOS-Category--ARC-compliant-code) available. I have previously used [HCYoutubeParser](https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser) to extract URLs suitable for use in an MPMoviePlayer.